# How to get VelocityEngine template from an external URL through getTemplate() method?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, velocity

I am working on an AppEngine-java project. I am using VelocityEngine as a templating tool to customize a Html file. I have placed my template file at google-cloudstorage. All i want is to initialize that file as a 'Template' through the getTemplate() method in Java. I need help here..

..just want to do this,

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.init();
Template t = ve.getTemplate("http://storage.googleapis.com/....bucket_name...../html_templates/....file_name....html");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out a method to do that but in a different way,

```
 try {
            BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("http://storage.googleapis.com/.....appspot.com/html_templates/....html").openStream());
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(input, baos);
            byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

    Reader templateReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)));
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

        context.put("template_field", getString(fieldVariable));
    ...

    StringWriter swOut = new StringWriter();
        Velocity.evaluate(context, swOut, "log tag name", templateReader);

    return swOut.toString()
}catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code will generate a string after reading a template through its URL and adding context to it, through Velocity Engine.